# storage duration of underlying character data with user-defined string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, user-defined-literals, storage-duration

Quick setup: I want to pass strings around in my program as a pointer and a size.  I have a String class and a user-defined literal for constructing literal Strings:

```
struct String { const char *ptr; size_t sz; };

inline constexpr String operator "" _string(const char *s, size_t sz) {
  return {s, sz};
}

int main() {
  auto s = "hello"_string;
  s.ptr[0]; //<-- is this access guaranteed to work?
}
```

Does the standard specify that the argument passed to my user-defined literal operator has static duration?  i.e. is the above code actually equivalent to writing:

```
int main() {
  String s{"hello", 5};
}
```

or is the compiler/linker allowed to leave me with a dangling pointer when I use the user-defined literal?

(Section 2.13.8 of N4527 did not seem to say anything on the subject of storage class of the argument to the user-defined string literal operators.  Any pointers into the appropriate section(s) of the standard would be appreciated.)

Comment: Section 2.13.8 aka [lex.ext]p5 does seem to say that the argument is a *string-literal*, and those have static storage duration.

Comment: @dyp I am not sure if that is clear though, I keep going back and forth on that

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That's why I didn't post it as an answer ;)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour What room for doubt? What am I missing? It calls them string literals, string literals have static storage duration, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [lex.ext]:

> If L is a *user-defined-string-literal*, let *str* be the **literal** without its *ud-suffix* and let *len* be the number of
>   code units in *str* (i.e., its length excluding the terminating null character). The literal `L` is treated as a call
>   of the form:
>
> ```
> operator "" X (str , len )
> ```

From [lex.string]:

> Evaluating a *string-literal* results in a string literal object with **static storage duration**, initialized from the given characters as specified above.

So:

```
"hello"_string;
```

is equivalent to:

```
operator "" _string("hello", 5)
```

As `"hello"` is a *string-literal*, it has static storage duration, so you will have no dangling pointer.

Comment: *"of the form"* seems a bit vague, it doesn't say *"equivalent to"*. Anyway, I agree with the basic notion.

Comment: @dyp Yeah, in other contexts in the standard "*of the form*" is usually presenting a syntactical structure (e.g. "an expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2 ... "). Poor wording choice imo.

Comment: There's [dcl.fct.def.general]p8, though, which is not syntactical; it might mean "equivalent to" in that instance.

Comment: The standard seems clear enough when _you_ say it.  Accepted, thanks!